# Count vars in get_defined_vars

Tags: php, arrays

I have unknown number of variables, for example:

```
$number_one = array(21,5,4,33,2,45);
$number_two = array(1,5,14,23,42,35);
$number_three = array(13,33,45,17,2,7);
$number_four = array(2,44,5,21,23,33);
```

I count all defined vars with `$arr = get_defined_vars();`

How can I count number of vars - in his case number of all arrays?

I used `foreach`, but maybe I don't do this properly.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $i++;
    echo '<br>';
    foreach ($value as $val) {
        echo $val.',';
    }
}
echo $i;
```

I don't know why result is 8 :/

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Comment: 4 vars for this case.

Comment: No,`[_GET] => Array ( ) [_POST] => Array ( ) [_COOKIE] => Array ( ) [_FILES] => Array ( ) ` these four are by default included in `get_defined_vars()`

Comment: Hmm this explains everything thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $number_one   = array(21,5,4,33,2,45);
    $number_two   = array(1,5,14,23,42,35);
    $number_three = array(13,33,45,17,2,7);
    $number_four  = array(2,44,5,21,23,33);
    $variable_s   = 'adsfadfdfa';
    $variable_n   = 22;

    $vararr = get_defined_vars();
    // We want to exclude all the superglobals
    $globalarrays = array(
        'GLOBALS', 
        '_SERVER', 
        '_POST', 
        '_GET', 
        '_REQUEST', 
        '_SESSION', 
        '_COOKIE', 
        '_ENV', 
        '_FILES'
    );

    $narrays = 0;
    foreach($vararr as $key => $variable) {
        if ( !in_array($key, $globalarrays) && is_array($variable) ) {
            echo $key . ' is an array<br />';
            $narrays++;
        }
    }

    echo '# arrays = ' . $narrays;
```

Notes:

- The code counts only arrays, no scalars (*is_array()*).
- It excludes the super global arrays like *GLOBALS*, *_POST*, etc.

Result:

> number_one is an array
>   number_two is an array
>   number_three is an array
>   number_four is an array
>   # arrays = 4

Comment: I just can change echo $i; from my code with echo $i - 4; :P

Comment: No, you cannot. In the constellation you have, there are 4 superglobal arrays set. In a different constallation others (like _SESSION, _ENV) might be set too. So, you have to ask if an array is one of the superglobal arrays explicitely in order to get the correct count.

Comment: how to count the other variables along with arrays.. Is there any way to know that?

Comment: Just remove the **&& is_array($variable)** part of the _if_ statement. Or, if you mean **only** the non-arrays, remove the other part.

Answer (score 2):

it is all because, `get_defined_vars()` returns certain predefined indexes like `GLOBALS`, `_POST`, `_GET`, `_COOKIE`, `_FILES` and other indexes which are user defined, here in your case, those are `number_one, number_two, number_three` and `number_four`

for more details on `get_defined_vars()` you can refer the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

As the user defined indexes, are only after predefined indexes, you can use `array_slice` to slice your defined array.

```
$number_one = array(21,5,4,33,2,45);
$number_two = array(1,5,14,23,42,35);
$number_three = array(13,33,45,17,2,7);
$number_four = array(2,44,5,21,23,33);
$arr = get_defined_vars();
$arr    = array_slice($arr, 5, count($arr));
echo count($arr);
```

This prints the 4.

Comment: I didn't know for globals, now I know how to make it.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The function `get_defined_vars()` gets all of the variables that are defined currently in the server including environment and server variables.

```
$number_one = array(21,5,4,33,2,45);
$number_two = array(1,5,14,23,42,35);
$number_three = array(13,33,45,17,2,7);
$number_four = array(2,44,5,21,23,33);
$arr = get_defined_vars();
print_r($arr);
```

Try this code and  see the output in your browser. I'm sure you'll get to know how many variables are actually defined(including those defined by you)

For Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php